# Applying for graduate programs, will missing classes count against me?

Tags: graduate-admissions, coursework

I'm working on some graduate school applications, and I've been wondering...
If I'm missing some classes these schools require(this is more relevant in different states)will my application be less desirable to that particular school, because I will have to take some extra classes in order to start that program.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to clarify the kind of program you're applying to. There's a big difference between programs like computer science, chemistry, etc. where students can sometimes "make up" undergraduate coursework after enrolling in the graduate programs, versus programs in fields like physical therapy, pharmacy, and dentistry, that strictly require certain prerequisites and won't consider applications of students without them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably inappropriate to say it always "count against you," but it is fair to say that it **will** be taken into consideration.

For instance, some schools may not admit you officially to the master's or doctoral program in a field if you are missing classes normally expected of students in a given program (for instance, if you're missing analytical chemistry and applying for a chemistry master's). In still other cases, you may be admitted to a program, but with no allowances actually made for the courses missing—that is, you'd be expected to pass the graduate-level courses just like everybody else enrolled in the program.

On the other hand, if you are missing *too* many "core" classes, then you will probably find yourself struggling to gain admission, since the admissions committee may (rightly?) feel that you have too much prior work to make up.

Comment: That helps, it's only two to three max. If they offered these at my current institution I wouldn't be concerned. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: When I heard "required," I was thinking of programs that *strictly* require students to have certain classes before starting the program to be considered for admission. e.g. many [Doctor of Physical Therapy](http://steinhardt.nyu.edu/pt/dpt/admission) programs. I don't think of "normally expected" as "required."

Comment: Yeah, I could have been more clear... Sorry about that!

Comment: @AustinMauldin Can you edit your question to be more clear, i.e. specify whether you meant "normally expected" coursework or "required" coursework?

Comment: @ff524: I think in the case you state, a provisional admission, if possible, would be the likely result.

Comment: From personal experience of people in my family, programs like those won't consider applications from people who don't meet their stated requirements. (If you haven't taken them as part of your undergrad degree, you have to take them at as a non-degree student at another school before you apply to the graduate program.)

Comment: @ff524: I think it depends on what the school's admissions options are. Our university allows students to be enrolled in the undergraduate courses for a while before beginning the "official" program.

Comment: Does that program have language like "To be considered for admission... you must meet the following requirements" or "Course prerequisites must be completed by the end of the spring semester (or quarter) prior to commencing the program" in its instructions to prospective students? From what I hear, PT and occupational therapy programs are very strict with requiring that the prerequisite coursework be completed before starting. I think many other health-related fields (pharmacy, dentistry) probably are as well.